# Visual Studio Express 2013 For Web Failed to create new Project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I had Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web installed on my machine running Windows 8. Windows update automatically updated my windows to Windows 8.1. After the update when I reopened VS Express 2013, I was unable to create a new project. I get the following error:

**Failed to create a 'ImageSource' from the text '..\Images\Medium.png'.**

I tried the following measures but to no effect:

- Reinstalled VS Express 2013
- Installed and Reinstalled *FastPictureViewer codec*
- Run VS as administrator
- Set Registery key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes.png - REG_SZ Content Type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found this solution:

Go to windows update of your PC and install all the optional an recommended updates.

Restart your pc and everything should work fine.